# How to convert flat array to a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

What is the best way to convert array like:

```
array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
```

to:

```
  array(
    array(1,2,3),
    array(4,5,6),
    array(7,8,9),
    array(10),
  );
```

I came up with something like:

```
$flat = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$colsLimit = 3;
$offset = 0;
$multi = array();

while($sliced = array_slice($flat, $offset, $colsLimit)) {
  $multi[] = $sliced;
  $offset += 3;
}
```

A better solutions are welcome.

Comment: Whats wrong with your solution ?

Comment: Check the "[See also](http://php.net/array_slice#refsect1-function.array-slice-seealso)" section of [`array_slice` documentation page](http://php.net/array_slice)

Comment: @zerkms thanks, missed this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has a built-in function that does exactly this: [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/array_chunk):

> Chunks an array into arrays with size elements. The last chunk may contain less than size elements.

Usage:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);
$result = array_chunk($arr, 3);
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/80035)

Answer (score 1):

A different approach using neither `array_slice` nor `array_chunk`

```
$flat = array( 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10 );

$multi = array( ( $multiIndex = 0 ) => array( ) );

foreach( $flat as $value )
      count( $multi[ $multiIndex ] ) == 3
    ? $multi[ ++$multiIndex ] = array( $value )
    : $multi[ $multiIndex ][ ] = $value
    ;

var_dump( $multi );
```